# Reading MySQL result using PHP in AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I was wondering if some one could explain how I can read a MySQL result array in AS3.

I am using:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://domain.com/get-api.php");
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
loader.dataFormat = flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlReq.data = urlVars;
urlVars.mySubmittedRateID = GlobalVariables.mySubmittedRateID;
urlVars.myPostcode = GlobalVariables.currentPostcode;
loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, getDataOnComplete);
loader.load(urlReq);
```

to pass a parameter (2 in fact) to the get-api.php file. In the file I PHP reading in the parameters and a normal SQL select where statement which gets all the results matching the parameters.

My getDataOnComplete function is:

```
private function getDataOnComplete(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(event.target);
    var resultsArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);
}
```

My PHP:

```
$row_array['done'] = "true";
return json_encode($row_array);
```

Error:

```
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
at Error$/throwError()
at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
at flash.net::URLVariables()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

For some reason I cant even get to the getDataOnComplete function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php mysql result will be array then

In php side you need to convert into result array into json_encode($result_array) like

```
echo json_encode($result_array); //Note here not return statement;
```

In as3 side

you can use latest AIR SDK having native JSON class (Here using AIR class) or [as3corelib](https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) to parse JSON data.

```
private function getDataOnComplete(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
  var resultObj:Object = event.target.data;
  var resultsArray:Object = JSON.stringify(resultObj);
}
```

For more details [pass-an-array-from-php-to-actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074043/how-can-i-pass-an-array-from-php-to-actionscript-3-flash)

Comment: And then a for loop in AS3 to get each record?

Comment: I get an error: 

Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
 at flash.net::URLVariables()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: For avoid those error change loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES to loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have updated my question with the latest code.

Comment: Check in php side not return just simply use echo statement. and also getDataOnComplete() bit changed it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also had to com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode as opposed to just JSON.decode. I will also try your latest suggestion.