# How can i send an array from php to as3 and show as list

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am building an air app in flash cs6 using as3. My database is on a web server and I use php to connect to my app, I need to send an array from php to as3 and populate it in a list in my app, I just need to know how to send and receive an array so I can print it in my app thanks

Comment: Send an array from PHP to as3? Do you mean have as3 contact the PHP server? For starters have you looked at `URLRequest` and `JSON.parse`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass an array from PHP to Actionscript 3/Flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074043/how-can-i-pass-an-array-from-php-to-actionscript-3-flash)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Actionscript 3

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://example.com/json.php"));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoaderCompleteHandler);

function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
    var json:Object=JSON.parse(urlLoader.data);
}
```

Now within `urlLoaderCompleteHandler` you can handle json as an object.

PHP

```
<?php
    $data=array("test"=>"Hello World!");
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Not quite sure why you deleted this - to me it looks better than the other answer here.

Comment: @Flexo Tidying up some old answers, it didn't look like it was going to help anyone so I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON](http://json.org/)

on the AS3 side you can find docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html)

on the php side use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Note that JSON is only available if you're targeting Flash Player 11+. For earlier versions, you can download a library [here](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json).